# error on importing wmi

Tags: python, import, wmi

hi
when I import wmi module I got this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       import wmi   File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wmi.py",
>   line 88, in 
>       from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch   File
>   "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\win32com__init__.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       import win32api, sys, os ImportError: DLL load failed: The
>   specified module could not be found.

what should I do

Answer (score 0):

This thread seems relevant:

http://old.nabble.com/Problems-importing-win32com-td24988589.html

Did you install Python as administrator?